# UIToolbar-how to add two button item in two line?

Tags: iphone

as title how to?the class method of UIToolbar is add the button all in single line

```
[contentToolBar setItems:items animated:NO];
```

but i want it can add in different line or multiple line, thanks

Answer (score 1):

That's not exactly the [HIG](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/Introduction/Introduction.html). So you've got to do it yourself.

Comment: hi, how to do?have to create own custom class?can give a reference code how to start i really need this, thanks

Comment: Just to echo Nikolai, this really isn't a good UI decision. You can create multiple UIToolbars and put them on top of each other in Interface Builder, but this could be grounds for having the app rejected from the App Store.